# python hangman game loops problems

Tags: python

I am have problems with my while loop for this hangman game that I am making. First of all it prints wrong answer like 5 time and I don know why? I am trying to get it too let e guess another letter as well, but with only six guess or its game over. here is what I have so far.

```
import drawHangman
import turtle




def main():

    #Do not change or remove code from herel
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.setup(400, 400, 200, 200)
    HG = turtle.Turtle()
    drawHangman.default(HG)


    #To here
main()   
#Start your program below here You may still need other import
import random
print(" Welcome to the HangMan game!!\n","You will have six guesses to get the answer correct, or you will loose!!!",)

lines = open("../WordsForGames.txt").read() 
line = lines[0:] 
                    #lines 24-28 Randomly generate a word from a text file
words = line.split() 
myword = random.choice(words)
print(myword)


words = myword
fake = '_'*len(myword)
count = 0
print(fake)

guess = input("Enter a letter you would like to guess: ")

fake = list(fake)  #This will convert fake to a list, so that we can access and change it.
for re in range(0, len(myword)):  #For statement to loop over the answer (not really over the answer, but the numerical index of the answer)
    if guess == myword[re]:  #If the guess is in the answer, 
        fake[re] = guess    #change the fake to represent that, EACH TIME IT OCCURS
        print(''.join(fake))  #converts from list to string
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong guess!, guess again")    
        count =+ 1
while guess == ''.join(fake):
    guess = input("Enter another letter you would like to guess: ")
    if guess == myword[re]:  #If the guess is in the answer, 
        fake[re] = guess    #change the fake to represent that, EACH TIME IT OCCURS
        print(''.join(fake))  #converts from list to string


main()
```

Comment: Why are there two calls to `main()`?  I recommend you take out all the drawing, and try to make a text version that just plays the game.  Once you can do that, put the drawing in.  Since we don't have hangman.py, we can test your code if you leave the drawing in.

Comment: it seems like all the code outside of the main function should probably be inside the main function. also you should try breaking the problem up into smaller tasks and encapsulating the code into different functions.